# Finding all combinations of elements of a set satisfying a specific condition

Tags: algorithm

Here's a problem i'm trying to solve :
I'm given a set of lines having slope m and constant c. Now I need to find the number of intersection points of these lines that intersect on the right hand side of the y axis . This essentially implies that for lines 1 and 2

```
                    c1>c2 and m2>m1
```

I need an O(nlogn) algorithm that counts the total number of intersection points on the right hand side of y axis (if the algorithm exists) . I can always do the brute force to get an o(n2) algorithm , but i'm looking for a faster algorithm .

Comment: Which intersection do you mean? Between line 1 and line 2? Or between line and X axis?

Comment: I need to find the number of intersection points between the lines in the given set , that lies on the right of x=0 .

Comment: What happens if you create a list of lines sorted according to your criterion? You could then iterate through the list and sum up the number of list entries. Complexity O(n log(n))

Comment: How do you sort based on c1>c2 and m2>m1 ?

Comment: This condition will not find all pairs of lines. x > 0 for (c1<c2 and m2<m1) as well since x = (c2-c1)/(m1-m2). While this doesn't change the complexity of any algorithm that works for the condition you give, you may have to run it a second time with the other condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two sorted vectors will do that.

1. Push all of the lines into vector v1.
2. Sort v1 by constant c. After that, v1[0] is the line with smallest c.
3. Traversal v1 from begin to end. For each element e in v1, we should only consider the element visited before(c1>c2). Now the task is to find among all of the visited element, the element with m2 > m1.
4. So we just push the element which have been visited into a vector v2.We should keep it sorted by slope m after every insert(self-balance BST will do this task). Since v2 is sorted by m, a binary search will tell you how many element satisfy m2>m1.

Sort is n log n.

Insert to v2 is log n(It can be achieved with self-balance BST, and it will invoke n times).

Binary search is log n(invoke n times).

So it's O(nlog n)

If you write this in C++, it will be like that(**I don't define v2, because you will implement a self-balance BST**):

```
struct line
{
    int c,m;
    line(int a,int b):c(a),m(b){}
    bool operator <(const line &a) const
    {
        return m>a.m;
    }
};
bool cmp(const line &v1,const line &v2)
{
    return v1.c<v2.c;
}
int main()
{
    vector<line> v1;
    v1.push_back(line(1,3));
    v1.push_back(line(4,1));
    v1.push_back(line(3,1));
    v1.push_back(line(2,2));
    sort(v1.begin(),v1.end(),cmp);
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)
    {
        int num=v2.find(v1[i]);//return the number of element whose m is larger than  v1[i].
        ans+=num;
        v2.insert(v1[i]);// in every step, the element e in v2 will satisfy e.c<v1[i].c
    }
    cout << ans;
}
```

That's all. If you have any question, leave a comment to me.

Comment: can you elaborate step 3 ? And step 4 should be done for every c belongs to v1 right ?

Comment: How is insert into v1 logn ? it should be atleast O(n) if i'm not wrong ( You've to visit n elements to insert them )

Comment: @Malice Insert it to v2. insert a element into STL::SET is log n. And STL::Set can be considered as a sorted vector.

Comment: step 3 seems to do for each element e in v1 , copy all elements from v1 to v2 such that it lies to the left of e . This has two steps : 1)For all N : executed n times 2) copy all elements left to v2(you've not accounted for this (2nd step))

Comment: @Malice Just insert the v1[i] to v2(v1[i] is the element we just visited before)

Comment: @Malice I'm very sad to tell you, STL::SET cannot do that. It may very complex to solve that task.

Comment: The BST will have to be augmented to tell us the number of elements that have m <= m2, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my solution because I think it's more simple to implement:

Let's say you got objects of Line and the following attributes are defined:

```
- m (slope,    initialized on start)
- c (constant, initialized on start) 
- pos_m ( default 0 value )
- pos_c ( default 0 value )
```

Now, you have a `V` vector of these lines, then:

1. Sort `V` by using key `m` on elements (O(nlogn)).
2. Iterate `V`, on index `i` set `V[i].pos_m = i` (O(n)).
3. Sort `V` by using key `c` on elements (O(nlogn)).
4. Iterate `V`, on index `i` set `V[i].pos_c = i`. (O(n)).
5. Let `result = 0` now iterate on `V` index `i` do `result += | V[i].pos_m - V[i].pos_c |` (O(n))

On sorting, if the compared value is equal then use the other key for deciding the order ( if both are equal, they are the same line ). For example, if on 1. two lines got the same slope, then let the constant be the decider.

Answer (score -1):

In the worst case, this problem is guaranteed to require O(n^2) operations.

Suppose I draw one line, then there can be no intersections. I can draw a line that intersects that line at a unique point. I can now draw a line that intersects both the preceding lines. I can continue drawing lines that intersect every previous line.

This means the number of intersection points could reach:

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n-1

Given an input of size n lines, the size of the output to this problem could be (N*(N-1))/2 points or about N squared over 2.

Hence, even just outputting the correct answer requires O( n^2 ) in the worst case.

edited, ignore the previous, I thought you wanted the actual points of intersection, and not just the count.

Comment: We just care about the number of intersection points. Output is a number.